# Image resize in CSS hover not working

Tags: html, css

I have to scale up the image when I hover over it, it should scale up to 300x225 pixels from 100x75 pixels. Layout seems to work fine, it's just width does not scale up when hovered. Thank you in advance. The image should not scale more than the 300x225 pixels.

CSS:

```
.hoverbox a .preview {
   display: none; 
}
.hoverbox a .preview img {
   display: inline; 
}
.hoverbox a:hover .preview {
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   top: -1em;
   left: -2em;
   z-index: 10;
   border-width: 1px 1px 6px 1px; 
   border-style: solid; 
   border-color: #fff7ea;
   border-radius: 3px; 
   -moz-border-radius: 3px; 
   -webkit-border-radius: 3px; 
   -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #161615;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #161615;
   box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #161615;
}
.hoverbox img {
   background: #fff;
   border-width: 1px 1px 6px 1px; 
   border-style: solid; 
   border-color: #fff7ea;
   border-radius: 3px; 
   -moz-border-radius: 3px; 
   -webkit-border-radius: 3px; 
   -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #161615;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #161615;
   box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #161615;
       padding: 2px;
   vertical-align: top;
   width: 100px;
   height: 75px;
}
.hoverbox li
{
   background: transparent;
   display: inline;
   float: left;
   margin: 3px;
   padding: 5px;
   position: relative;
 }

.hoverbox .preview {
   width: 300px;
   height: 225px;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <section>  
         <h1 class="headline">Feast your eyes.</h1>
         <ul class="hoverbox">
            <li>
                <a href="#"><img src="200opt.jpg" alt="descr"/><img src="200opt.jpg" alt="description" class="preview" /></a>
            </li>
         </ul>

    </section>
```

Thank you

Comment: `.hoverbox .preview:hover` instead of `.hoverbox .preview`

Comment: thanks, its wierd. Still displaying width of odd 50px, but height is ok.

Comment: Hard to say - seems to be working for me. On how many browsers have you tried this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this approach using Jquery:

```
$('img').hover(function(){

$(this).width('500px');
$(this).height('400px');


}, function(){

    // set default image width & height

$(this).width('400px');
$(this).height('300px');


})​
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/GxjUt/3/)

Answer (score 1):

```
.hoverbox img:hover{
  width: 300px;
  height: 225px;
}
```

Working Fiddle with your class - http://jsfiddle.net/cDxgj/2/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. it seems to not work at all, displaying the right height, but the widht is just about 50px or so. Seems to be like some margin or padding is squashing it. Not sure

Comment: Post a link where we can firebug it

Comment: Thanks, it is still locally on my PC. It seems to be working fine for other people in fiddlejs or smth. I have tested it on IE, Chrome, FF

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use `img:hover` rather than `a:hover` in your CSS?
No point scaling the anchor tag. Seems like you are trying to make the room bigger, rather than the image in room?
If you want the anchor tag to scale as well, then you just use `position:absolute;`

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul class="hoverbox">
          <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="200opt.jpg" alt="descr"/><img src="200opt.jpg" alt="description" class="preview" /></a>
           </li>
</ul> **/* close ul*/**
```

Comment: Thanks, the ul is closed in my notepad. Odd